# Intuit.Ipp.Data.Qbo.CustomerQuery query with & in the name

Tags: intuit-partner-platform, quickbooks-online

How do you use Intuit.Ipp.Data.Qbo.CustomerQuery to query a name like:

Tom & Jerry's

This case has 2 special characters that are causing the query to fail. One being & and the other being '. I've tried to use Uri.EscapeDataString and it doesn't work. Any advice?

Answer (score 1):

The SDK does not encode the ampersand correctly, so you will need to use DevDefined and deserialize the response with the SDK. Code sample: https://gist.github.com/IntuitDeveloperRelations/6024616

Answer (score 0):

you would need to xml encode the string.

thanks
Jarred